# Trying to get a sliderbar to alter a textfield value in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, textfield

I have a sliderbar that takes input from the textfield and resets its position accordingly; however, I cannot figure out how to do the following:

1. Make it so that the sliderbar repositions itself for any value within the range, not just non-decimal inputs.
2. Make it so that the textfield value changes accordingly as the sliderbar is toggled.

The code can be found below.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

```
<div>
<input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="2" step="0.001"/>
<input id="input" type="text" value="1"/>
</div>

<script>
    var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
    $('#input').change(function(){
        slider.value=parseInt(this.value)
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a sliderbar that takes input from the textfield and resets its
>   position accordingly;

I don't see how that work with the code given since you're using `parseInt` and would need `parseFloat` for that. Anyway, below is what you asked for:

```js
$('#input').change(function() {
  $('#slider').val(parseFloat(this.value))
});
$('#slider').on("input change", function() {
  $('#input').val(this.value)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="2" step="0.001" />
  <input id="input" type="text" value="1" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use parseInt() since both need to be string.

```
<div>
<input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="2" step="0.001"/>
<input id="input" type="text" value="1"/>
</div>

<script>
    var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
    $('#input').change(function(){
        slider.value=this.value
    });
</script>
```